# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp Server Response after POST Android

Tags: android, android-async-http

I am using LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp to get/post data from/to my server. I know that when I call the .get method, the JSON response is stored in the s string as shown below:

```
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("https://example.com/generateToken.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) {}
```

If, however, I am posting to the server, how do I get my server's response? I used the template here for posting:
http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html

Specifically my code looks something like this:

```
    params = new RequestParams();

    params.put("first_name", firstName);
    params.put("last_name", lastName);
   client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("xxx.com/createCustomer.php", params, responseHandler);
```

My server takes these inputs and returns a token. How do I retrieve this token? Do I have to call the .get method as before immediately after the .post code above? Or is it automatically echoed somehow? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just the same as your Get request.

The Last Paramter in the post Method needs an suitable ResponseHandler.

```
  params = new RequestParams();

    params.put("first_name", firstName);
    params.put("last_name", lastName);
   client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("xxx.com/createCustomer.php", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) {}
);
```